# svg in img tag not showing (modified with illustrator clipping mask)

Tags: html, image, svg, adobe-illustrator

I have a svg image of an instagram icon that I exported with clipping mask in Illustrator. [image: saved as svg]
However, when I I try to display it, it doesn't show in any browser. (Other social icons showed)

[image: showing social icons]

I used the img tag to display the svg as it is displayed finely with other icons. Am I doing something wrong? Does img tag support clipping mask images?
Sorry that I don't have much experience with svg. Any suggestion is very appreciated! Thanks!
Here is my code:

```
<nav id="socialNav">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#facebook.html" target="_blank"><img src="../../_images/social-facebook.svg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#instagram.html" target="_blank"><img src="../../_images/social-instagram_color-01.svg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#twitter.html" target="_blank"><img src="../../_images/social-twitter.svg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#googleplus.html" target="_blank"><img src="../../_images/social-googleplus_test.svg"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="56.7px" height="56.7px" viewBox="0 0 56.7 56.7" enable-background="new 0 0 56.7 56.7" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
<g>
    <defs>
        <path id="SVGID_1_" d="M28.2,16.7c-7,0-12.8,5.7-12.8,12.8c0,7.1,5.7,12.799,12.8,12.799C35.299,42.299,41,36.5,41,29.5
            C41,22.5,35.2,16.7,28.2,16.7z M28.2,37.7C23.7,37.7,20,34,20,29.5c0-4.5,3.7-8.202,8.2-8.202c4.5,0,8.2,3.7,8.2,8.202
            C36.4,34,32.7,37.7,28.2,37.7z M41.5,13.5c1.602,0,2.898,1.298,2.898,2.9s-1.298,2.9-2.898,2.9c-1.602,0-2.9-1.298-2.9-2.9
            S39.899,13.5,41.5,13.5z M49,8.9C46.4,6.2,42.7,4.8,38.5,4.8H17.9c-8.7,0-14.5,5.8-14.5,14.5v20.5c0,4.302,1.4,8,4.2,10.701
            C10.3,53.1,13.9,54.4,18,54.4h20.4c4.3,0,7.899-1.399,10.5-3.899C51.6,47.9,53,44.2,53,39.9V19.3C53,15.1,51.6,11.5,49,8.9z
             M48.4,39.9c0,3.101-0.899,5.601-2.7,7.3c-1.8,1.7-4.3,2.6-7.3,2.6H18c-3,0-5.5-0.898-7.3-2.6c-1.8-1.8-2.7-4.3-2.7-7.4V19.3
            c0-3,0.9-5.5,2.7-7.3c1.7-1.7,4.3-2.6,7.3-2.6h20.6c3,0,5.5,0.9,7.3,2.7c1.7,1.8,2.7,4.3,2.7,7.2v20.6H48.4z"/>
    </defs>
    <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
        <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  overflow="visible"/>
    </clipPath>
    <g id="LF6r1C.tif_2_" clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)">

            <image overflow="visible" enable-background="new    " width="601" height="514" id="Layer_0_3_" xlink:href="B91C5780217A8A7F.png"  transform="matrix(0.0961 0 0 0.1609 -2.4072 -11.1685)">
        </image>
    </g>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code for the SVG in your question?

Comment: added the code, thanks so much!

Comment: Just copy/pasting the svg source into a new file I was able to view it in the browser. (Chrome) Funny colours though. - greens and blues and not fully filled in. Opened it in Inkscape - Oh! of course - the colour come from an image I don't have. Is the image (`B91C5780217A8A7F.png`) present in the same folder as the svg?

Comment: @christie - Thanks for the image, but actually I really was asking if it exists in the same folder as the svg. It's referenced with a relative URL so wont work if they aren't both in the same folder. Something else to consider is how ridiculous it is to use a nice, small svg and then to use a great big, whopping image like that simply for a gradient colour. Seems possible that a far better option would be to create an svg gradient and do away with the link to the external resource. Whatcha think, would that work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here'e the image with a few changes. The clip-path's coords have instead been used to create a path, which is then filled with a radial gradient. The file is now simply a filled path, rather than a clipped image. It's going to scale better, is 99% smaller (1283 **bytes** total vs 135Kb just for the gradient) and avoids the problem inherent with linked (vs embedded) files. Enjoy! Hit the Blue button to see it.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 56.7 56.7" viewBox="0 0 56.7 56.7" y="0px" x="0px" width='56.7' height='56.7'>
<defs>
 <radialGradient id="a" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cy="47.1" cx="16.48" gradientTransform="matrix(2.215 0 0 2.215 -20.03 -57.24)" r="25.3">
  <stop stop-color="#f9d363" offset="0"/>
  <stop stop-color="#f26c1f" offset=".3658"/>
  <stop stop-color="#ce0665" offset=".6829"/>
  <stop stop-color="#541fdb" offset="1"/>
 </radialGradient>
</defs>
<path d="m28.2 16.7c-7 0-12.8 5.7-12.8 12.8s5.7 12.8 12.8 12.8 12.8-5.8 12.8-12.8-5.8-12.8-12.8-12.8zm0 21c-4.5 0-8.2-3.7-8.2-8.2s3.7-8.202 8.2-8.202 8.2 3.7 8.2 8.202c0 4.5-3.7 8.2-8.2 8.2zm13.3-24.2c1.602 0 2.898 1.298 2.898 2.9s-1.298 2.9-2.898 2.9c-1.602 0-2.9-1.298-2.9-2.9s1.299-2.9 2.9-2.9zm7.5-4.6c-2.6-2.7-6.3-4.1-10.5-4.1h-20.6c-8.7 0-14.5 5.8-14.5 14.5v20.5c0 4.302 1.4 8 4.2 10.7 2.7 2.6 6.3 3.9 10.4 3.9h20.4c4.3 0 7.899-1.399 10.5-3.899 2.7-2.6 4.1-6.3 4.1-10.6v-20.6c0-4.2-1.4-7.8-4-10.4zm-0.6 31c0 3.101-0.899 5.601-2.7 7.3-1.8 1.7-4.3 2.6-7.3 2.6h-20.4c-3 0-5.5-0.898-7.3-2.6-1.8-1.8-2.7-4.3-2.7-7.4v-20.5c0-3 0.9-5.5 2.7-7.3 1.7-1.7 4.3-2.6 7.3-2.6h20.6c3 0 5.5 0.9 7.3 2.7 1.7 1.8 2.7 4.3 2.7 7.2v20.6h-0.2z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="url(#a)"/>
</svg>
```